# allocating object again

Tags: iphone, memory-management

I have a following code:

```
[chart removeFromSuperview];
[chart release];
chart = nil;
BNPieChart *aChart = [[BNPieChart alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
self.chart = aChart;
[aChart release];
```

And as I want, *chart* is deallocating, but in variable is still something, next when I want to assign *aChart* to *chart* I've got EXC_BAD_ACCESS. So I decided to assign nil to chart.

Is this a good practice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even better, replace:

```
[chart release];
chart = nil;
```

With:

```
self.chart = nil;
```

You get BAD_ACCESS because when you assign a retained/copied property with dot syntax it gets auto-released. Therefore it will work correctly even like this:

```
[chart removeFromSuperview];
BNPieChart *aChart = [[BNPieChart alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
self.chart = aChart;
```

`self.chart = aChart` will do the release for you.

Answer (score 1):

HI badeleux ...i think not because you get error or crash EXE_BAD_ACCESS . that you are attempting to accessing something that you already release .

Answer (score 1):

If you already have chart set as a retained property, rather than using

```
[chart release];
chart = nil;
```

You can just write;

```
self.chart = nil;
```

You can do this because the automatic code resulting from your @synthesize chart will do the release for you. Many regard this as better practice as it will ensure messages aren't accidentally sent to non-nil objects.